# Rails initialize model value from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm fairly new to Rails and I'm running into an issue which I can't seem to find a resolution to. My model represents an RMA in the system. When you generate a new instance of the model I'd like to lookup the previous RMA number and generate a new one. The RMA # design looks like `RMA-{year}-NNN` => `RMA-2015-001`.

My current implementation leverages `after_initialize` to accomplish this. However during my testing I noticed that making a call to the database during this method seems to causes an infinite loop.

**This is what my code looks like:**

```
after_initialize :after_initialize

def after_initialize
  self.rma_number ||= generate_rma_number()
end

def generate_rma_number
   new_rma_array = Array.new
   new_rma_array.push("RMA")
   new_rma_array.push(Time.now.year)

   # Get the last RMA
   last_rma = Rma.select(:rma_number).order('id desc').first

   # If there is no RMA
   if(last_rma == nil)
     new_rma_array.push("001")
     return new_rma_array.join('-')
   end

   # Split the string
   current_rma_array = last_rma.rma_number.split('-')

   # Increment the RMA
   new_rma_array.push((current_rma_array[2].to_i + 1).to_s.rjust(3, '0'))
   return new_rma_array.join('-')

 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infinite loop is caused by the RMA lookup that you're making in the generate_rma_number method.

```
last_rma = Rma.select(:rma_number).order('id desc').first'
```

Because what you want is before_create not after_initialize. After initialize will trigger every time a model is initialized. Even if that models already exists in the db.

Comment: This won't execute until it's saved to the database, correct? I was kind of hoping to show this value to the user when they are creating the RMA. However I suppose that's not entirely necessary.